# Can Linq to excel stand on pc that excel program is not installated?

Tags: linq, excel

I need to merge many excel file to one, but I wonder if linq to excel can work on pc that excel program is not installed?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the fine manual](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel#welcome-to-the-linqtoexcel-project) `linqtoexcel` has a dependency on JET and ACE. The former is installed with Windows, the latter is not (but [can be downloaded](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=13255)). Excel is not a dependency.

I'm generalising what's written in the x64 support section:

> You will also need to make sure to have ... the Access Database Engine installed on the computer.